# Limit function call to maximum 15 times in a miunte's interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component in my ReactJs app (just started learning), with a search box. The onChange handler of that input box is attached with a keydown event listner in the componentDidMount lifecycle method. Now when this event is triggered it further triggers a function which makes a fetch api call. But, I need to fulfill a condition where no matter the number of times this function gets triggered the number of api calls should stop after 15 times(at maximum 15 api calls) in a minute.

I have tried using debounce with a interval of 4s but that does not seems to serve my purpose as the user will have to wait for 4 secs between each keystroke.

```
class SearchPage extends Component {

  state = { searchString: "" };

  componentDidMount() {
      document
        .querySelector(".search-planets")
        .addEventListener("keydown", this.onKeyDown());
    }
  }

  onKeyDown = () => debounce(this.fetchResults, 4000);

  fetchResults = () => {
    const { searchString } = this.state;
    const { updateSearchResults, updateFetchStatus } = this.props;
    updateFetchStatus({
      isFetching: true
    });
    fetch(APICALL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
       ......
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

.....
          <h2 className="text-center">Star Wars</h2>
          <InputGroup>
            <Input
              className="search-text"
              placeholder="Search text"
              value={searchString}
              onChange={updateResults}
            />
          </InputGroup>
```

How should I modify my above code to enable the user to make at max 15 api calls in a minute's interval?

Comment: Throttling and debouncing are two different things. What you may actually be asking about is a combination of debouncing (so there's not a request-per-keystroke) *and* a cap on calls over a given time period, which throttling may or may not address directly. Your debounce timeout is unrelated to your throttling requirements, e.g., you might debounce with a 0.25-0.5sec period, but throttle at 15 reqs/min.

Comment: Yes @Dave, this is exactly what I am trying to achieve a combination of debounce and throttle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running a timer using `setInterval` while keeping the time passed (denoted by **time** in state) in state. While keeping a condition in callback of `setState` to check when 60 minutes have passed, **time** is reset to 0. Meanwhile keeping a limit on the number of times the `fetchResults` function gets called.

```
...
startTimer() {
    this.setState({
      isOn: true,
      time: this.state.time,
      start: Date.now() - this.state.time
    });
    this.timer = setInterval(
      () =>
        this.setState(
          {
            time: Date.now() - this.state.start
          },
          () => {
            //reset timer and count after 1 minute
            if (this.state.time > 60000) {
              this.resetTimer();
              this.setState({ count: 0, time: 0 });
            }
          }
        ),
      1
    );
  }

  fetchResults = () => {
      this.startTimer();
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    if (this.state.count > 15) return;
    ...
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a throttle function instead of debounce

```
onKeyDown = () => throttle(this.fetchResults, 4000);
```

More information [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/).

Comment: That only solves part of the problem--the user would still need to wait 4s between result fetches, which is crappy UX. The correct answer is a mix of debouncing and throttling.

Comment: You better keep a button to fetch data, that way you aren't fetching typos in a time limit (Crappy UX)

Comment: Ugh, also no. That's not how type-ahead searches work almost ever. That's not a type-ahead at all, that's just plain old search.

Comment: You can also detect 'enter press' if you have call limits

Comment: Yes, you can; also not type-ahead. The question is explicitly about type-aheads.

Comment: I don't think typeahead search were designed to have search limits, but you can check this article: https://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-to-throttle-and-debounce-an-autocomplete-input-in-react

Comment: They may, of both varieties (debounce and throttling), although debouncing alone is more typical. Particularly if they're hitting an external API w/ its own rate limits. I'm completely aware of how to combine debouncing and throttling--otherwise I wouldn't be able to make the comments I've been making.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I am using solution with:

```
setInterval(() => yourFinction(), timeInMilliseconds);
```

Like:

```
    onKeyDown = () => {
      this.fetchResults();
    }

    setInterval(() => this.fetchResults(), 4000);
```

Maybe it'll be helpful.

Comment: Explain downvote. This solution is working in the same situation in my project

Comment: I didn't downvote (yet), but this doesn't really solve the problem: the user would still need to wait 4sec between API requests, which is an unacceptable UX. This is like using a shotgun to remove a mole: effective UX requires precision and responsiveness, not blanket delays.

Comment: The edit is even worse. Now there will be new intervals created every time the user hits a key, leading to as many fetches as there are keystrokes, every four seconds, offset by the delta in time between keystrokes. (And a redundant anonymous function, but that's of secondary importance.)

Comment: Thanks for you explanation